# Symfony 2 : use MongoDB as session storage

Tags: mysql, mongodb, session, symfony, pdo

I have an application built on Symfony 2 using DoctrineORM / MySQL to store data and PdoSessionHandler / MySQL to store sessions.

I am trying to replace DoctrineORM to DoctrineODM to use MongoDB instead of MySQL.
But I don't want to have MySQL and MongoDB on my server (to ease maintenance, upgrades, etc.).

So I'm looking for replace PdoSessionHandler by my own service plugged on MongoDB.

I'm newbie in NoSQL and before starting this, I want to know if :

- there are known problems (conceptual, bugs, performance impact, difficult to use/configure, etc.) for using MongoDB to store sessions.
- it is a good pratice to use MongoDB instead of MySQL for session storage

**EDIT**
In Symfony > 2.1, there is a service to use MongoDB as session storage ([tuto to use MongoDB as session storage](http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/11/05/storing-sessions-in-mongodb-with-symfony2/)):

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure it in `app/config.yml`

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id: session.handler.mongodb

services:
    session.mongodb:
        class: MongoClient
        arguments: [ "mongodb://localhost:27017", true]

    session.handler.mongodb:
        class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\MongoDbSessionHandler
        arguments: [ "@session.mongodb" ]
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not a "technical" (I have found tuto to configure MongoDB). I search for information about conception/architecture (it is a good practice or not) and the possible implications (like performances, or limits) of using MongoDB for session storage